# How to fill Gridview from two different database tables but the record is not duplicate in Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a User privilege form, where I load grid from `Administrator` table, then I insert data from `GridView` with a `Checkbox` property in a new `User` table in database, it works perfectly.
But in next condition I want to load grid from both of two tables, first `User` table where the data is shown with `Checkbox` checked true property, and the second `Administrator` table, where data is shown with check box checked false property.

If u understand my question, so please help me.
My Code is:

```
protected void CmdUserRights_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    StrSql = "Select Name from Sys.tables";
    StrSql = StrSql + " Where Name='" + "User_" + CboUserId.Text + "'";
    DataSet rs = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);
    if (rs.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        StrSql = "Select * from User_Administrator";
        StrSql = StrSql + " Order by serial_no asc";
        DataSet rs2 = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);
        GvUserPrivilege.DataSource = rs2.Tables[0];
        GvUserPrivilege.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        StrSql = "Select * from " + "[User_" + CboUserId.Text + "]";
        StrSql = StrSql + " Order By serial_no asc ";
        DataSet rs4 = (DataSet)MethodClass.ConnectionToQuery(StrSql);
        if (rs4.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GvUserPrivilege.DataSource = rs4.Tables[0];
            GvUserPrivilege.DataBind();
            foreach (GridViewRow rows in GvUserPrivilege.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)rows.FindControl("chk");
                ChkBoxRows.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The statement is a bit unclear, but if you have two related tables, then it would be better to write a Join query with all conditions implemented in SQL and bind your GridView to that query. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Alex Bell.

Try to join tables like this:

```
SELECT
    Administrator.*,
    (User.somefield IS NOT NULL) checked
FROM Administrator
LEFT JOIN User
    ON [join condition here]
```

If some record exists in User table, then expression (User.somefield IS NOT NULL) will be true (you need to use some NOT NULL column for this). Otherwise, it will be false.